# Add or Update Property on JSON object with Mapping Template (AWS API Gateway)

Tags: aws-api-gateway, vtl

In my AWS APIGW Rest API, I'm trying to add and/or update a property on the request body (JSON) that is submitted.  Every example I could find deals with constructing a new JSON object, not updating the existing one.

In the Integration Request Mapping Template, my incoming data body looks like this.  If it's a new object getting posted, it won't have an ID.  If it's an existing object, it will have an ID.  **The goal here is to ALWAYS ensure it has an ID** by either getting the existing one and setting it back to the JSON object or adding a new one.

```
// New object getting added, No ID
{
    "first_name" : "Toby",
    "last_name" : "Keith"
}


// Existing object getting updated, Has ID
{
    "id" : "abcdef"
    "first_name" : "Toby",
    "last_name" : "Keith"
}
```

My Integration Request Mapping Template looks like this:

```
## Do we have an existing id? (this is correctly pulling the existing ID)
#set( $id = $input.path('$.id') )
## If no ID, create one using the RequestID.  (This is also working)
#if ( $id == "" ) #set( $id = $context.requestId ) #end
## Get the entire json request string as json object
#set( $json_obj = $input.json('$') )
## Overwrite the ID on the json body to make sure we always have one
## [HERE IS THE PROBLEM]
## This isn't setting the id back on the $json_obj
#set( $input.path('$.id') = "$id" )
{
    "data": "$util.escapeJavaScript($json_obj).replaceAll("\\'","'")"
}
```

I want the value for "data" above to be a JSON string which includes an id as well as first_name and last_name.

I've tried numerous variations on setting the property, but no luck as of yet.  None of these are working.

```
// Tries to update the JSON string I think, not the $json_obj
#set( $input.path('$.id') = "$id" )
// These cause error (because of quotes?)
#set( "$json_obj.id" = "BBBB" )
#set( '$json_obj.id' = "CCCC" )
// Doesn't work
#set( $input.path("$json_obj.id") = "DDDD" )
#set( $json_obj.id = "EEEE" )
```

As a plan B, I could break the $json_obj into key/value pairs and loop over them checking for an ID and either add or update it.  Essentially building out a new JSON object, but that seems like the less preferable way than setting the property directly.

Does anyone know how to add/update a property on a JSON object with mapping templates?

Answer (score 10):

I found the issue.  This line is NOT converting the body payload into a JSON object like I thought.  After more careful reading of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference), I see that it examines a JSON path expression and returns a matching JSON string.

```
#set( $json_obj = $input.json('$') )
```

To convert it into an object, I needed this syntax:

```
#set( $json_obj = $util.parseJson($input.json('$')) )
```

The corrected mapping template now looks like this

```
## Do we have an existing id? (this is correctly pulling the existing ID)
#set( $id = $input.path('$.id') )
## If no ID, create one using the RequestID.  (This is also working)
#if ( $id == "" ) #set( $id = $context.requestId ) #end
## Get the entire json request string as json object
#set( $json_obj = $util.parseJson($input.json('$')) )
## Overwrite the ID on the json body to make sure we always have one
## This isn't setting the id back on the $json_obj
#set( $input.path('$.id') = "$id" )
{
    "data": "$util.escapeJavaScript($json_obj).replaceAll("\\'","'")"
}
```

However, this leads to a secondary problem of now converting the JSON object back to a properly formatted JSON String.  If I print out the JSON object, I get unquoted strings for some reason.

```
# Print out $json_obj 
$page_obj
```

Results in

```
{first_name=Toby, last_name=Keith}
```

I'll open a new question for that issue if I am unable to solve it.

2021/11/30 UPDATE:

It's been a while since I worked on this project but for completeness, I ended up being able to set the ID on the input before pulling the object into JSON.

```
## Pull the existing ID
#set( $id = $input.path('$').id )
## If empty, assign new ID
#if ( $id == "" ) #set ( $id = $context.requestId ) #end
## Assign the ID to the input
#set( $input.path('$').id = $id )
## Now pull the data out as an object
#set( $data = $input.json('$') )
```

The real difference is `path('$.id')` is now `path('$').id` to properly assign the id to the input before extracting the input into a JSON object.

Comment: Can you please share how you fixed the latest issue about converting the JSON object back to a properly formatted JSON String?

Comment: @GiorgioCatenacci I updated my answer with my final solution.

Comment: @ChrisSmith In my case, I don't have an id, I want to create a new attribute/field called id. How do I do that?